# Binding a style in resourcedictionary XAML

Tags: windows, xaml

i have this code in my ResourceDictionary:

```
        <ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:Controls="clr   namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Maps" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:vb="clr-namespace:GPS.ViewModel"
    >


       <vb:VMGps x:Key="theme"/>

<Style x:Key="styleMap" TargetType="Controls:Map" >
        <Setter Property="ZoomLevel"   Value="{Binding ZoomLevel,Source={StaticResource  theme}}" />
    </Style>
```

But doesn't work.... give me a error with the value binding

Comment: words "*doesn't work*" didn't add any information, you won't post question if the code works. Instead, explain how it doesn't work exactly? How you use that style? What is `theme`? And check VS output window for binding error.

Comment: I am sorry, i changed the question ....  i have a error with the Binding value

Comment: please, post the exact error message

Comment: the error message is `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException appears in the app.xaml.cs before the  InitializeComponent();